# Why is this Civic's boost bar pink?

Tags: civilization-6

Just as [Valamas asked about Technologies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292715/7882), why is the boost bar below Mercenaries pink while Civil Service and Medieval Faires are gray? I have boosted all three Civics, and I haven't researched any of them. My only guess would be that the boost to Mercenaries came from a Goody Hut except I definitely have more than eight land combat units.

[image]

Note: In the screenshot, I haven't chosen my next Civic to research yet. Going back into the game and choosing one (and switching around) has no effect on any of the bars.

Comment: I'm playing as Roosevelt for America and using the Quick UI mod, but I've noticed this before with the vanilla game and other leaders/civilizations.

Answer (score 1):

The pink bar signifies that you are currently researching that boosted civic. Similarly [a blue bar on technologies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292715/why-does-the-research-item-have-a-blue-bar)  signifies you are researching that tech.

The game automatically selects a civic or tech so you don't waste a turn if you forget to pick a new one

Comment: What about the paragraph after the screenshot? "In the screenshot, I haven't chosen my next Civic to research yet."

Comment: The game automatically selects a civic or tech so you don't waste a turn if you forget to pick a new one.

Comment: He's asking why it's boosted, not why it's selected.

Comment: He's asking why the bar is pink, not why it is boosted. The filled in arrow indicates that it is boosted (so is civil service and medieval fairies). It should be pink as that's what the game picked for him automatically to research next. 

The OP theorized that the reason for boosting was somehow related to the pink bar, however the reason is irrelevant.